# Pop-up a generated PDF file using DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf-generation

I've been googling a lot but I couldn't find anything helpful for my case.
I need to pop-up a PDF document using Spring MVC `DispatcherServlet` after invoking a method that generates it with a `@RequestMapping`.

Here's the code of how I generate the PDF File :

```
private MailMerge mailMerger = new MailMerge();
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<>();
vars.put("companyName", "TeamWill Consulting");
vars.put("siret", "123456789");
vars.put("financedAmount", "13500");
vars.put("payment", "400");
vars.put("duration", "36");
File pdf = mailMerger.toPdf("Devis.docx", vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return your file in servlet response

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(
@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName, 
HttpServletResponse response) {
try {
  InputStream is = ...;
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
  response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: the file name is unknow since it's generated randomly using `toPdf` method